# How to offer files in ruby on rails with authentification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My problem is, I upload files to my server, and atm the uploaded files are located under an asset directory, but I don't want all users grant the access to the files, but if the file is located under an asset directory, all users can download them etc.

But if a user want to alter his file, then he should get access to them f.e. with js (think that i use js as an editor).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you use **Paperclip** gem. Read this post about protected file download: http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/8/29/protecting-your-paperclip-downloads

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advise, but i m using paperclip as well an there is the same flaw. If you store a pic or a file with paperclip it is stored in an asset dir and if you browse to this dir your server will gladly give this file to anyone -.-

Comment: But maybe i have to configure the assets another way